# VB Net - How to add tuple to the list

Tags: vb.net, list, tuples

I've been searching for a day to search this topic
for example:

```
#I don't know how to create it to the script so I describe it like this

list  = {("Cat", "Dog", "Cow"), ("Milk", "Egg", "Pizza")}

list(0)
#("Cat", "Dog", "Cow")
list(0)(0)
#Cat
list(0)(1)
#Dog
list(1)(1)
#Egg
```

anyone know how to do that on vb net ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
Dim list = new List(Of String()) From 
{ 
    new String(){"Cat", "Dog", "Cow"}, 
    new String(){"Milk", "Egg", "Pizza"} 
}
```

or

```
Dim list = new List(Of String())
list.Add({"Cat", "Dog", "Cow"})
list.Add({"Milk", "Egg", "Pizza"})
```

Now you can use:

```
' prints Cat, Dog, Cow
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", list(0)))
' prints Cat
Console.WriteLine(list(0)(0))
' prints Dog
Console.WriteLine(list(0)(1))
' prints Egg
Console.WriteLine(list(1)(1))
```

Comment: how to do function.add("Cat", "Dog", "Cow") so it will return {"Cat", "Dog", "Cow"} ? or something like that

Comment: @user3786930 If you use `Dim bla = {"Milk", "Egg", "Pizza"}` the `{`/`}` will create a new array, in this case a new string array. So if you want to pass "Cat", "Dog" and "Cow" as a single parameter to a function taking an `string()` or `IEnumerable(Of String)`, you can use `foo.bar({"Milk", "Egg", "Pizza"})`.